# Build against .Net 2.2 fails after .Net Core 3.1 installation with "Could not load file or assembly NuGet.ProjectModel"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild, msbuild-task

## Build started failing suddenly

Our solution contains projects targeted against .Net Standard 2.0, .Net Core 2.2 and .Net Framework 4.5. Quite a nice mix. It is being built with `dotnet -c Release MyProject.sln`.

One day we started suffering from the following error, but only on one of our build slaves:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly. [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.ProjectModel, Version=5.4.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified. [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'NuGet.ProjectModel, Version=5.4.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromMemory(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash) [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task) [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups() [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore() [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:  [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:  [D:\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
```

We have had some issues in the past, after .Net Core 3.1 was installed on the slaves, but pointing to `2.2.100` in `global.json` fixed them.

Now, we have tried to fix the new problem searching multiple sources for `Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.ProjectModel...` and similar stuff, tried many different solutions and workarounds, updates and repairs of .Net Core and Visual Studio Build Tools. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

Finally we have spot something weird in the output of `dotnet build -c Release MyProject.sln -v diag`:

```
MSBuildSDKsPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\
MSBuildToolsPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.110
```

It turned out, that we've had `MSBuildSDKsPath` variable set in the system and pointing to the SDK, which broke the SDK downgrade with `global.json`. No idea, if this was set manually by some of my colleagues or during installation of "something", but it was there and sucked ~2 days of my life :-)